# canvas object display on html

Tags: javascript, html, object, testing, canvas

So I am practicing javascript, and I made a lotto game with some animation in the background. This is how it looks:

[image: image of oage]

I am wondering if it is possible to make the balls that bounce in the background to go over the `div` in which the `title, random numbers and button` is. So basically the balls bounce in front of the `div` not behind it.

Here is the link to the code: https://github.com/Frago23/Frago1321

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Please [create a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Add a second canvas with id 'myBallCanvas'.

```
<canvas id="myBallCanvas"></canvas>
```

Then add this to your css

```
   #myBallCanvas {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

Finally, change your javascript so that you're selecting your new canvas

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#myBallCanvas');
```

And change the z-index of all your #frame, #frame2... selectors to 0

Basically lower z-index elements will be placed behind higher index elements. Note that any elements you want to use z-index on must have a specified position property (either fixed, absolute, or relative)

Oh and for next time, you should include a link to your code in your main post. If you only put it in my answer other people won't see it

Comment: How do I make the connection between `css` and the `script` in which the balls object is made? Because in the `html` file I added the scripts like `<script src="lotto.js"></script>` but how can I add a class to the balls then?

Comment: You should post all of your code here if you want a more detailed response. In any case, I've edited my answer. You don't need to connect your css and javascript. You can think of it as both the css and script files modifying your html

Comment: Here is my code. Both files are uploaded. I created them differently than you said. https://github.com/Frago23/Frago1321

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: The problem is that now the whole `canvas` was placed in front. My goal was to place only the balls. I edited my post with the link

Comment: Then you just add more than one canvas ;) Of course they would have different id's so you could select whichever one you want. And instead of selecting just 'canvas' in the css as I showed above, you would select '#myBallCanvas' (because the # selects a specific id)

Comment: I managed to do it with a second canvas. Check it out if you want: https://github.com/Frago23/Frago1321

Comment: Awesome! If my answer was helpful please upvote :)